Micronaut multimodule project, Controller path not found
I have been trying to setup Micronaut project to support multimodule gradle build, where I would split project API per gradle module. I have hard time making it work though. Seems like the Controller I extracted to separate module is not properly picked up by Micronaut and route is not properly registered.
project structure:

src

main

kotlin

Application.kt




build.gradle.kts


api

src

main

kotlin

Controller.kt






build.gradle.kts



root project build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.25"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.9.25"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.25-1.0.20"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "4.4.4"
    id("io.micronaut.aot") version "4.4.4"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.stosik"

val kotlinVersion = project.properties["kotlinVersion"]

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    ksp("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    ksp("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")

    implementation(project(":api"))

    compileOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}


application {
    mainClass = "com.vonage.ApplicationKt"
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}

graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.stosik.*")
    }
    aot {
        optimizeServiceLoading = false
        convertYamlToJava = false
        precomputeOperations = true
        cacheEnvironment = true
        optimizeClassLoading = true
        deduceEnvironment = true
        optimizeNetty = true
        replaceLogbackXml = true
    }
}

api module build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.25"
}

group = "com.stosik"
version = "0.1"

val kotlinVersion = project.properties["kotlinVersion"]

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http:4.6.5")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5:4.5.0")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-rest-assured:4.5.0")

}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Controller.kt class
@Controller
class Controller {

    @Get("/test")
    fun test(): HttpResponse<String> = HttpResponse.ok("All good")
}

When I run:
curl "http://localhost:8080/test" 

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

I receive:
{"_links":{"self":[{"href":"/test","templated":false}]},"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Page Not Found"}]},"message":"Not Found"}% 

Any idea what I may have missed?
